# "Implementing" a class in Java

Tags: java, class, testing

I have a homework assignment for a Java class where it tells me to "implement" a class that they outline for me (Tells me what it does, and various attributes of the class, as well as some methods), as well as to "write some java statements that test the class," and I was wondering what exactly the question is asking me to do.

I'm not looking for answers to my homework, but I just don't exactly know what that means to "implement" the class, and to "test the class" for a homework problem. I can handle the actual coding, if there is any involved.

Thanks

Comment: *I can handle the actual coding* Good. **Implement** == **Code**.

Answer (score 2):

The homework has defined an "interface" to "implement", so your class should have the same methods and fields, and then finally to "test" it you should write unit tests.

Comment: So am I taking what they outlined and making an actual class out of it?

Comment: So.. I'm not taking the class that they outlined and coding it, but I am writing a class that is "implementing" the class they made?

Comment: coding what they outlined and implementing it are synonymous.

Comment: So how would I write statements to test the class? Would the statements just be creating instances of that class? Or perhaps creating an instance and using some methods through it?